# Reset/change Emoji color for human features

Tags: color, emoji

I inadvertently hit the wrong color for a human emoji.  Holding it down does nothing and I really need this particular emoji to be correct.

Comment: What device are you using? Do you want to reset all of the emojis? Or just one?

Comment: Is this for iOS or a Mac?

Answer (score 9):

You need to long press on the emoji for which you want to change the skin tone, this will show a skin tone picker.

You can do this on macOS in the Emoji &Symbols picker, and on iOS using the Emoji keyboard.

Skin tone settings are saved per-emoji.

If long press doesn't bring up the picker, you have a different problem.

Comment: Just want to add that this works on macbook as well as iphone (i.e. same shortcut on both macOS and iOS, which is neat)

Answer (score 0):

It's only a workaround, but one way to let you input the correct emoji in MacOS would be to go to [this page](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), copy the emoji with the color you want, and set up a text replacement for it in system preferences/keyboard/text/replace with

In iOS you could do the same thing using its own text replacement setting.